# Add linked server from SQL Server 11.0.5058 to SQL Server 10.50.4000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I tried to add a linked server running on SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.4000) from SQL Server 2012 (11.0.5058).

I keep getting this error:

> The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do you want to keep the linked server?

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Are there any restrictions on building linked server between different versions of the database?

Okay, created this linked server using tsql code

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
@server='xxxLinkedServer', -- here you can specify the name of the linked server
@srvproduct='',     
@provider='sqlncli', -- using SQL Server Native Client
@datasrc='xxxxxx',   -- add here your server name
@location='',
@provstr='',
@catalog='smpro5'  -- add here your database name as initial catalog (you cannot connect to the master database)
-- Add credentials and options to this linked server
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
@rmtsrvname = 'xxxLinkedServer',
@useself = 'false',
@rmtuser = 'xxxxSqlUser',             -- add here your login on Azure DB
@rmtpassword = 'xxxxxxxx' -- add here your password on Azure DB
```

When open the server node and view all tables, get the "Failed to retrieve data for this request" error.

[image]

I can access the 2008r2 server via UI, without any trouble.
[image]

I do have one concern, that is my main database sits on Amazon cloud. Could this cause any problem?

Okay, thanks for all the answers guys. I think it is the problem caused by the firewall setting on the 2008r2 server. I am going to ask server admin to open that port for me.

Thanks to system administrator, it now works.

[image]

Special thanks to  Remus Rusanu, thank you for pointing me to the right direction !!!

Comment: Can you ping that address? Can you telnet on 1433/1434? Can you connect through SQLCMD / SSMS? My guess is firewall...

Comment: Yes, of course. I can access ms sql server 2008 via UI freely. Just the linked server won't work. I have also pinged the IP address.

Comment: Are there any restriction on building linked server between sql 2008 sp2 and sql 2012?

Comment: http://sqlserverversions.blogspot.co.nz/ shows different versions of sql server.

Comment: Try creating linked server using tsql [sp_addlinkedserver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Is the target server a named instance?

Comment: No, it should be fine across versions. I go back and forward all the time. Are you sure it isn't a named instance?

Comment: I access the sql server via IP address from UI as well as building linked server.

Comment: Any firewall rules preventing SQL Server from establishing outbound connection?

Comment: The main server is on the amazon cloud, we have a few linked connection on that main database 2012. Unless there is firewall restriction on the 2008r2 server that I do not know.

Comment: Hi Remus, thank you very much for your answer. I am considering the firewall options right now.

Comment: It shouldn't be a firewall issue if you're able to connect using SSMS. I just generated a script from a linked server I set up, and noticed that it only specifies two parameters for sp_addlinkedserver: EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'<remote FQDN or IP>', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'. It does specify two logins though, one with @useself=true and all other params NULL, and the other with @useself=false and both local (an account with permissions on the local server) and remote logins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your administrator I'd like to confirm that the problem has been caused by firewall restriction. SQL port is opened so you can complete linked server setup.

Cheers, mate

Comment: Answered by my own system administrator, priceless....

Comment: What is the difference between connection of creating a linked server and executing the query?